# Are multiple Groups of Should possible in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elastic search 6.5.

I am trying to put together a query that will do the following:

search for documents where

- primary key values must be either 85, 0, 95, or 3.
- where a sub key1 value must start with 4444 or empty string. OR,
- where a second sub key2 value must be start with 5555 or empty string.

it also includes some date range criteria.

I feel like i need two groups of 'should'.  because at least 1 match must occur in both groups. but they can't be combined.. because the at least 1 of the subkeys must be matched too.  The "must" below is incorrect, because it 'should' be a Should but two groups of should aren't possible.

Any idea how i can be done?

I have put together this query:

```json
{
  "size" : 200, "from": 0,
  "query":{
        "bool": {
            "should": [{ "term": { "primary_key": "84"}},  
                       { "term": { "primary_key": "3"}},
                       { "term": { "primary_key": "0"}},
                       { "term": { "primary_key": "95"}}],
            
            "must":   [{ "match_phrase_prefix": { "subkey1" : "65200010100780"}}, 
                       { "match_phrase_prefix": { "subkey2" : "00228315303"}}],
                     
          "filter": [  { "range": { "start_date": { "lte": "2018-11-01" }}},
                       { "range": { "end_date": { "gt": "2018-11-01"}}}] 
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since at least one match must occur in both groups of "should", I would do it like this, with two `bool/should` in the `bool/must` clause:

```json
{
  "size": 200,
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "primary_key": "84"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "primary_key": "3"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "primary_key": "0"
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "primary_key": "95"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "subkey1": "65200010100780"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase_prefix": {
                  "subkey2": "00228315303"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "start_date": {
              "lte": "2018-11-01"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "end_date": {
              "gt": "2018-11-01"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. didn't know you can nest those clauses... that helps.

Comment: A bool query is a regular query that you can definitely nest